# Use TFS to remove files on Azure environment

Tags: tfs, azure-web-app-service, tfsbuild, azure-powershell

I have an Azure environment which I deploy code to from TFS 2017 RTM.

Most unfortunately, I only add code, not replace code (can't change that due to requirements) so I need to manually delete a folder on the Azure environment - right now through a FTP-client.

Is there a way to write a .ps1-script or bat-script, which connects to the environment, and deletes a folder from inside TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Insert the following before uploading the wanted data to replace - an FTP Upload:

[image]

The `FolderToRemove` is a folder containing a Readme.md file (could've been empty)

Comment: Indeed, @Andy-MSFT - but there was a time limit I had to get past :)